# native boot of a windows subsystem linux distro, as a standard distro at bootup of windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, debian-based

Is it possible to boot the Wlinux (*a windows linux subsystem distro*) filesystem natively instead from the windows bootmanager (or refind grub etc)?

Like a dual boot system, but be able to either boot in at start, or access the linux system via wsl.

For reference I have a surface pro 5, and I know that its neccesary to disable secure boot ...etc. More curious of whether this can be done or not, and if so is there a particular way to do it succesfully ?

Thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/ is a better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while SuperUser cover more general questions that include topics like dual booting.  https://superuser.com/search?q=dual+boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. WSL is not a full desktop replacement or even a VM. It aims to reduce the need to use VMs. If you want to dual-boot, you'll need to grab a Linux iso. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq.